Lower central series of a nilpotent lie group versus that of its lattice
Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in some nilpotent lie group $N$. Is it true that the quotients $\gamma_{i}\Gamma/\gamma_{i+1}\Gamma$  of successive terms in the lower central series of $\Gamma$ are isomorphic to the quotients $\gamma_{i}N/\gamma_{i+1}N $ in the lower central series of $N$ (after tensoring with $\mathbb{R}$)? Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the lie algebra associated with $N$. I read somewhere that the graded lie algebra $gr(\mathfrak{g})$ is isomorphic to the graded lie algebra $\bigoplus \gamma_{i}N/\gamma_{i+1}N$. I was wondering how much of this information can be recovered from a lattice. Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.
